# jQuery animation not working (number countdown/count-up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, animation, counter

I have a script that looks like the following:

```
function powerClick(level, cost, user) {
    clicks = Number(clicks) - cost;
    addBPS();
}
function addBPS() {     
    var from = {property: $('#current').text()};
    var to = {property: Number(clicks)};
    jQuery(from).animate(to, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function() {
            $('#current').text((Math.floor(this.property)));
        }
    });
}
```

The first function runs when a button is clicked, and adjusts the value of `clicks`. Then it runs the function `addBPS` (right below it).

The function `addBPS`, however, does not completely countdown to the number stored in the variable `clicks`. A lot of the time, the function `powerClick` sets the variable `clicks` to 0. However, when the function `addBPS` is ran, the counter does NOT go all the way down to zero.

Why is this?

Comment: Have you inserted console logs into the code yet to double check that all variables are what you expect them to be?

Comment: @A2345sooted I've used alert boxes and I'm sure that the variables are what I want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems I see here:

1. It may be because clicks is not defined globaly? So each time it ends running the first function the value is destroyed.
2. Try replacing this.property by to.property or from.property?
3. I'd recommend using less generic variable names like "to" or "from". You may find yourself using reserved keywords someday without thinking. (happened to me)

   ```
   var clicks;

   function powerClick(level, cost, user) {
       clicks = Number(clicks) - cost;
       addBPS();
   }
   function addBPS() {     
       var data_before = {property: $('#current').text()};
       var data_after = {property: Number(clicks)};
       jQuery(from).animate(to, {
           duration: 1000,
           step: function() {
               $('#current').text((Math.floor(data_after.property)));
           }
       });
   }
   ```